# Exclude group if at least one row within it matches the condition

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sample table :

```
-----------------------------------
    name    | price |    status   
------------+-------+--------------
 apple      | 50.00 |
 apricot    | 30.00 |
 cherry     | 32.00 |
 orange     | 25.00 |
 pine-apple | 35.00 |
 orange     | 20.00 | out-of-stock
 apricot    | 35.00 | out-of-stock
 grapes     | 30.00 | out-of-stock
```

I need to retrieve records where `price` is less than `40` and exclude records where for the same `name` `status` value is `out-of-stock` at least once.

The desired result is represented below:

```
------------
    name
------------
 cherry      
 pine-apple
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600dce/2)

Comment: I don't understand. Which are the conditions? Price < 40 AND Status <> 'out-of-stock'?

Comment: @Oli seems i need some sub-query ...which i lack in that

Comment: ohh I understand now.... sorry

Comment: @Galma i need to list out the fruit which is worth below 40 and should be there in stock

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to avoid sold out fruits.

```
select name
from fruits f1
where price < 40.00
and not exists (select * from fruits f2
                where f1.name = f2.name
                  and status = 'out-of-stock')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` and `IS NULL` check :

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM fruits t1 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT name 
            FROM fruits
            WHERE status = 'out-of-stock') t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
WHERE t1.price < 40
  AND t2.name IS NULL
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600dce/19)

Or `IN`

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM fruits t1 
WHERE t1.price < 40 
  AND t1.name NOT IN ( SELECT name
                       FROM fruits
                       WHERE status = 'out-of-stock')
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/600dce/24)

Comment: @x-code : There were no column or table names specified, so I've chosen them, that's where errors were coming from.